# Trying to find the Fourier series of $f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is a piecewise function that includes $E\;sin(\omega\;t)$.

Tags: fourier-series

Here's the full function I'm trying to find the Fourier series to:

$$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : -\frac{\pi}{\omega}\leq t\lt 0 \\
       E\;sin(\omega t) & : 0\leq t\lt \frac{\pi}{\omega}
     \end{array}
   \right.,\;\;\;f\;\left(t\ + \frac{2\pi}{\omega}\right) = f(t)$$

At first, I tried this the non-complex way and got:

$a_0 = \frac{E}{\pi}$

$a_n = \frac{E\;\omega}{\pi}\int\limits_0^L sin\left(\frac{\pi\;t}{L}\right)cos\left(\frac{n\;\pi\;t}{L}\right)dt = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : n\neq 1\\
       E & : n=1
     \end{array}
   \right.,\;\;\;L=\frac{\pi}{\omega}$

$b_n = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : n\neq 1\\
       E & : n=1
     \end{array}
   \right.\;\;\;$ by the same method as $a_n$.

Which seems to give a Fourier series that is not even a series and doesn't fit the initial function:

$$\mbox{Fourier series} = E\left[\frac{1}{\pi}+cos(\omega\;t)+sin(\omega\;t)\right]$$

Obviously I've really messed up somewhere.

I then tried the complex Fourier series and got stuck. I can't really show every step as there are a lot of them but I can show the first and last.

$c_n = \frac{E}{2L}\int\limits_0^L\;sin(\omega\;t)e^{-i\frac{n\;\pi\;t}{L}}$

$ = ...$

$ = \frac{E}{4L}\left[(n-1)\omega\left(1-e^{-(n-1)i\;\omega\;L}\right)+(n+1)\omega\;\left(\; e^{-(n+1)\;i\;\omega\;L}-1\right)\right]$

And now I'm completely lost. Is there a trick to this Fourier series? Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your calculation of $a_n$, only the odd values of $n$ give $0$.  To do the computation, use the angle addition formulas.